# Making Struts work with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, frameworks, struts2

I am new to `jsf` and recently i have project where we want to move our front end from `jsps` to `jsf`, we are using `Struts2` as our MVC layer and `spring` as our transaction layer so what I am trying to understand is:

1. Can I have JSF integrate with Struts and both works fine without any issues (how will jsf managed beans map to struts Actions)?

I would appreciate if someone can share an example of doing this.

Comment: please add your comments so that we all can share proper cummulative understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 provides JSF Plugin provides support for JavaServer Faces components with no additional configuration.
Just go through the Plugin documentation to get an idea how plugin integrate JSF and Struts2

- [Struts2-JSF Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/jsf-plugin.html)